# How to create a list of values in Firestore with Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Im have a Collection called: Players 
Inside there each document has a value of posx and posy

i want to create an Array with Arrays for each document
Like: [[posx1,posy1][[posx,posy2]...]

if i put a print inside the .addOnSuccesListener it works and prints the list but
when im outside there and i try to print the list it returns empty

What i am doing wrong? Thanks

```
val myDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
var posiciones = ArrayList<Array<String>>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    myDB.collection("players")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                posiciones.add(
                    arrayOf(
                        document.get("posx").toString(),
                        document.get("posy").toString()
                    )
                )

            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
    //i get []
    println("Testing: "+ posiciones)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `get` is *asynchronous* and returns *immediately*.  Your code will go on to execute the `println` before anything else happens.  `posiciones` will be empty at that time.  Then, some time later when the query is complete and the database results are available, the success callback will be invoked, and the array will get populated.  Only after the callback is received is it a good idea to read the contents of `posiciones`.